# NDSolve very slow

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I am trying to run this code to get the output from `NDSolve` for 4 dynamical equations. However, I have two issues:

(1) It is taking a very long time (can reach several hours for a given instance) although the problem is not that difficult and shouldn't take that long (!). Also it seems to act slower/faster if I vary the value of `Scalar1`, but it is not clear if there is any linear trend in this.

Any advice would be appreciated on how to speed it up.

In the code below, please keep `k=0` in function input variables, and import (example, using `InterpEr=Import["InterpEr.wdx"]`) the three uploaded interpolation functions that will be called in the code below (download from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8z5kssmx66cp7xe/AACUDcPuOofkFjN0gf0auinKa?dl=0)).

For example try `Scalar1` values between 1 and 1000, and observe the long delays in NDSolve.

```
c = 3*10^8;
λ = c/(1.1424*10^10);
Mu0 = 4 *Pi* 10^-7;
m0 = 9.1093837015*10^-31; 
e = 1.602176634*10^-19; 
n = 10; 
m = 100;
omegaHz = 2*Pi (1.1424*10^10);
Δϕ = 2 Pi/m;

InterpEr = Import["InterpEr.wdx"]
InterpEz = Import["InterpEz.wdx"]
InterpHphi = Import["InterpHphi.wdx"]

Er[r_?NumberQ, t_?NumberQ, z_?NumberQ, k_?NumberQ] := Module[{er},
  er = InterpEr[r, z];  
  er Cos[omegaHz t + k Δϕ]
  ]
Ez[r_?NumberQ, t_?NumberQ, z_?NumberQ, k_?NumberQ] := Module[{ez},
  ez = InterpEz[r, z];  
  ez Cos[omegaHz t + k Δϕ]
  ]
Hphi[r_?NumberQ, t_?NumberQ, z_?NumberQ, k_?NumberQ] := Module[{hphi},
  hphi = InterpHphi[r, z];  
  hphi Cos[omegaHz t + k Δϕ]
  ]

Scalar1 = 1;
ErScaled[r_?NumberQ, t_?NumberQ, z_?NumberQ, k_?NumberQ] := 
  Scalar1 Er[r, t, z, k]/((m0*c^2)/(e λ)); 
EzScaled[r_?NumberQ, t_?NumberQ, z_?NumberQ, k_?NumberQ] := 
  Scalar1 Ez[r, t, z, k]/((m0*c^2)/(e λ));
BphiScaled[r_?NumberQ, t_?NumberQ, z_?NumberQ, k_?NumberQ] := 
  Scalar1 (Mu0*Hphi[r, t, z, k])/((m0*c)/(e λ));

ss = NDSolve[{D[tt[zz], zz] == γ[zz]/
     Sqrt[γ[zz]^2 - pr[zz]^2 - 1], 
   D[rr[zz], zz] == pr[zz]/Sqrt[γ[zz]^2 - pr[zz]^2 - 1], 
   D[γ[zz], zz] == 
    D[rr[zz], zz] ErScaled[rr[zz], tt[zz], zz, 0] + 
     EzScaled[rr[zz], tt[zz], zz, 0], 
   D[pr[zz], zz] == 
    D[tt[zz], zz] ErScaled[rr[zz], tt[zz], zz, 0] - 
     BphiScaled[rr[zz], tt[zz], zz, 0], rr[0.0] == 0, 
   tt[0.0] == 0, γ[0.0] == 1.1174, pr[0.0] == 0}, {rr, tt, 
   pr, γ}, {zz, 0.0, 1.76}, MaxSteps -> ∞]
```

Please note that this is my attempt to use `NDSolve` to solve the following set of equations:

$
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}t(z)}{\mathrm{d}z} = \dfrac{\gamma(r, t; z)}{\sqrt{\gamma(r, t; z)^{2}-p_{r}(r, t; z)^{2}-1}}
$

$
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}r(z)}{\mathrm{d}z} = \dfrac{p_{r}}{\sqrt{\gamma(r, t; z)^{2}-p_{r}(r, t; z)^{2}-1}}
$

$
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\gamma(r, t; z)}{\mathrm{d}z} = \dfrac{\mathrm{d}r(z)}{\mathrm{d}z} E_{r}(r, t; z) + E_{z}(r, t; z)
$

$
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}p_{r}(r, t; z)}{\mathrm{d}z} = \dfrac{\mathrm{d}t(z)}{\mathrm{d}z} E_{r}(r, t; z) - B_{\phi}(r, t; z)
$

which have $E_{r}, E_{z}, B_{\phi}$ as the given (uploaded) functions and the following 4 dependent variables ($z$ is the independent variable):

$ t = t(z)$

$ r = r(z)$

$\gamma = \gamma(r, t; z)$

$p_{r} = p_{r}(r, t; z)$

(2) Was my choice to solve this set using `NDSolve` a good choice? Are there any other/better methods (other than `NDSolve`) to solve this set of equations efficiently?

So far, the output from `NDSolve` seems to me like numerical noise. For example, after `NDSolve`, if we plot the function $\gamma$, which had initial value 1.1174 at $z$=0.0, we see that its value is fluctuating around the same value (it should be increasing or decreasing with $z$):

```
Plot[γ[zz] /. ss[[1]], {zz, 0.01, 1.75}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"z", "γ[z]"}, PlotLabel -> "Scalar" Scalar1]
```

[image]

I am trying to increase `Scalar1` in the hope (convincing myself?) to find out that it may be a matter of scaling, but I am starting to wonder whether something else could be wrong in this code/method?

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: It takes about 15 seconds on my machine. Also you don't need to use `Module` - for example write: `er Cos[omegaHz t + k Δϕ]` as `InterpEz[r, z] Cos[omegaHz t + k Δϕ]`

Comment: @flinty Just 15 seconds! That's quite different from what I get. Did you try to do it a few times with different `Scalar1` values between 1 and 1000?  And did you mean that `Module` is a potential reason for slow down? I used it just to make sure the variables inside it are local and not mixed with any other global variables used before or later.

Comment: Which version of _Mathematica_ are you using? I'm using 12.1. `Module` will be a little slower - you don't need to localize variables as you can inline them into the expressions.